# Compatibility level 90 not showing in SQL Server Express 2016

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server Express 2016 I'm not seeing how to set a database compatibility level to "90"

I've tried

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name 
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = { 90 | 100 | 110 | 120 }
```

But the error says "Valid Values of the database compatibility level are 100, 110, 120, or 130.

My application is trying to set compatibility_level to 90. I don't have a way to change the script at this time.

I also tried to change it in Options but the "90" level is not showing up there in the drop down. Is there a way I can add "90" to the compatibility level drop down? Do I need to download something for SQL Server Express 2016  to offer compatibility mode of 90 SQL Server 2005?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2005 is not supported anymore since 2005. Can you upgrade your database to a newer versions of SQL?

Comment: The error message is telling you that SQL Express 2016 does not support backward compatibility that far. It's pretty clearly stated when the message says *Valid values of the database compatibility level are 100, 110, 120, or 130*, which means compatibility doesn't extend to pre-100 levels.

Comment: There's lists of supported compatibility levels per SQL version here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level

Comment: @Bestter, "SQL SERVER 2005 is not supported anymore since 2005". That would be funny.

Comment: @Andrew Since 2015 :-)

Comment: If you cannot change your code, you are constrained to use as maximum SQL Server 2012